# CSV file created by app script has a problem

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, export-to-csv

I have the following code in my app script application:

```
  ...

  // Create CSV content
  var csvContent = "Beneficiário*,Conta/IBAN*,Tipo*,Informação complementar,Montante*,Email de Notificação\r\n";
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    csvContent += row.join(",") + "\r\n";
  });

  // Create and save CSV file in the same folder as the spreadsheet
  var csvFile = folder.createFile("MapaPagamentos.csv", csvContent, MimeType.CSV);
```

This works well and generates my CSV file.

I then import it into a program, which does NOT read the file.

If I open Excel and do "import data" from the CSV file, use "," as the separator and UTF-8 encoding, saving the resultant file, it works (meaning the second program reads the data well).

The question is how to "simulate" this process in the code, without having to use Excel?

Thanks

Comment: About `The question is how to "simulate" this process in the code, without having to use Excel?`, in your situation, where is your `Excel` file?

Comment: What do you mean? I simply open the CSV file with Excel on my computer.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `What do you mean?`, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. About `I simply open the CSV file with Excel on my computer.`, you want to update `Excel` on your local PC using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

Comment: No. I want to generate a file in the app script application and have the same result without having to open the file in Excel afterwards!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I believer your issue is "I then import it into a program, which does NOT read the file." which is you can not open the converted CSV file in another application.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct @TheWizEd

Comment: What application are you trying to open it in?

Comment: It is the online banking platform.